# Image inserted in xls sheet but doesn't appears !

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Insert image in xls sheet throgh php code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4040602/insert-image-in-xls-sheet-throgh-php-code)

Hello All,
              it feels great that after the help topics and Questionnaire on blog post i am able to insert the image in xls sheet using PHP5,and i am sure about this because befor inserting the image the size of xls file is 15 KB but after inserting the image the size is 127 KB. but when i open up the xls sheet it doesn't get appeared. what could be the reasons.I am using OPenOffice Calc to open up the xls sheet.Hope you all will be cooperative as always.

Cheers !!